# How to change repo with magit emacs?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I need to work with a few different git repositories. How to switch between them using magit? Magit allows me to choose a directory when I just start it.. But it is not clear for me how to switch to another repo if required. I've looked at magit cheatsheet and docs but haven't found an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just use dired or bookmark to switch to other file. Then call magit from there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can call `magit-status` with prefix-arg (<kbd>C-u</kbd>), it will prompt you for git repository. So if you keybinding for `magit-status` is <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>, you can do <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>, it will prompt for git repo.

You can also set the variable `magit-repo-dirs` to a directory (do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`magit-repo-dirs`<kbd>RET</kbd> to know more) and it will prompt you for all git repositories in `magit-repo-dirs`.

If you use projectile you can use the fact that it remembers your project directories and use it populate `magit-repo-dirs`, I have this in my init file to achieve this

```lisp
(eval-after-load "projectile" 
  '(progn (setq magit-repo-dirs (mapcar (lambda (dir)
                                         (substring dir 0 -1))
                                       (remove-if-not (lambda (project)
                                                        (file-directory-p (concat project "/.git/"))) 
                                                      (projectile-relevant-known-projects))))

         (setq magit-repo-dirs-depth 1)))
```

The code above is executed after `projectile` is loaded. It gets the list of projects known to `projectile` by doing `(projectile-relevant-known-projects)`, iterates through them and adds the projects that have `.git/` folder to `magit-repo-dirs`, it also sets `magit-repo-dirs-depth` to 1 so magit looks for git repos only in the top directories.

Answer (score 6):

I've found that if you use projectile, the easiest is to just set the following:

```
(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'projectile-vc)
```

Now you can use `C-p` `p` `s` (`projectile-switch-project`) and it will then immediately call `projectile-vc`, which if you have `magit` installed just calls `magit-status` in the project root. Simple!

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice package by John Wiegley called "Springboard" that might be useful for you.

https://github.com/jwiegley/springboard

It depends on `helm` and/or `ido`, and it allows you to execute arbitrary commands on the basis of files that might be in a different directory to the whichever file is currently in the active buffer. It's a little difficult to illustrate it in a non-verbose way (the README explains it well), but just to use your question as an example:

- Assume you are working on a file `1.el` that is part of a git repo
  but you want to run `magit-status` for a separate file `2.el` which
  is in another repo altogether.
- Using `M-x springboard` for `helm` or `ido-switch-buffer` for `ido`
  gives you a list of candidate files.
- By focussing on `2.el` (but not selecting it) you can then invoke
  arbitrary commands as if you were working within that file's
  directory.
- So, if you were to focus on `2.el` and then call `magit-status` from
  the candidate list, you would get the normal `magit-status` window
  for the repo associated with the file `2.el` and then once you
  have finished working with that you can just exit magit and `1.el`
  will be the active buffer and everything will be as it was before `springboard` was invoked.

It is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Magit uses current working directory of your current buffer when you execute magit-status. If other answers fail, here is inefficient but always working alternative:

1. Close magit current buffers (if any) (`q`)
2. Change directory to the one with your repo (`M-x cd`)
3. Start magit again (`M-x magit-status`)

(Inefficient because magit will be restarted)

Answer (score 0):

Updating on the accepted answer, here is the code that worked for me in Emacs 25. `remove-if-not` was not a known function, for some reason.

```
(eval-after-load "projectile" 
'(progn (setq magit-repo-dirs (mapcar (lambda (dir)
(substring dir 0 -1))
(seq-remove (lambda (project)
          (not (file-directory-p (concat project "/.git/"))))
        (projectile-relevant-known-projects))))
(setq magit-repo-dirs-depth 1)))
```